# How can I suppress an error message when using move with a wildcard on an empty directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using the following command to move files from source to destination:

```
move c:\src\* c:\dst
```

This works when there are files in `src` but gives the following error message when the directory is empty:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How can I suppress this error? This is a cosmetic/management/UX issue, as if there are no files to move then I don't need to take any further action.

Comment: You could try `move c:\src\* c:\dst 2> nul`...

Comment: @aschipfl: I'd rather not suppress other messages that may be genuine errors.

Comment: `move c:\src\* c:\dst 2>&1 | findstr /V /C:"volume label syntax"`

Comment: @Aacini: is it guaranteed that the string "volume label syntax" will not appear in a genuine error message?

Comment: **NO**. I just shown an example of how you can "not suppress other messages that may be genuine errors". It is up to you to choose the right text to filter. For example, you may use this: `move c:\src\* c:\dst 2>&1 | findstr /V /C:"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"`

Comment: Ops, I forgot the last dot! It must be `/C:"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."` **`;-)`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your real goal is to conditionally move files only when files exist in the source folder.

```
dir /b /a-d c:\src\* >nul 2>nul && move c:\src\* c:\dst
```

Comment: If files with a particular extension must always be present in the source folder, you may use the simpler `if exist c:\src\*.ext move c:\src\* c:\dst`